# Reputation cap and Process of applying cap

Tags: discussion, reputation

I've noticed there is a reputation cap of 200 per day max.

Let's assume a question/answer gaining reputation more than 200 in a day, then believe the cap will limit the reputation to 200. And let's say that particular question/answer hasn't gained any reputation on the following day. Will the balance which was capped on previous day will be awarded? or the reputation stays at 200?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reputation does not carry over to coming days. So if you get 25 upvotes on an answer (normally earning 10 points each) on day 1 and zero upvotes on day 2, you get 200 in reputation on day 1 and zero on day 2.

Comment: Is that fare decision? If that person earns 200 next day loosing previous day reputation could be fine, else that is not fare. This is my opinion only.

Comment: @Sayan Fair or not, that is how all Stack Exchange sites works.

Comment: Do note that receiving bounties and getting questions accepted gives you rep that is not capped, so 25 upvotes on an answer may cap out at 200, but if said answer is accepted, you will have gained 215.

Comment: I can confirm that the points do not carry forward. I had one answer with 35 upvotes and I only got some of those points